# Receive data from axios post request with React in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, reactjs, post, axios, form-data

I'm working on a big form with a lot of inputs and select fields. I send the post request with axios and I'm using FormData() object with append method for all of the fields.

Everything is fine, just the data I receive in my controller is not what I actually expect. I mean, this is the example of one of the select field:

```
<select onChange={this.props.handleSelect} name="select1">
  <option value="default">Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
  <option value="2">Else</option>
  <option value="3">Whatever</option
</select>
```

I set state of the Form with setState:

```
setState({ select1: target.options[target.selectedIndex].innerText });
```

So the state is "select1": "Whatever" (The point is, I'm not using the value from that field)

Then I append this select field before the request like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('select1', this.state.select1);
```

And after the post request, in my laravel controller I try to dd() with request all and get this:

```
"select1": "3"
```

So the data is sent without any problem, but I just receive the numeric value of selected option, not the text I try to send. Maybe I've just misunderstood something, so if it's the case, please, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you log this.state.select1 what do you get ?

Comment: When I select an option from select1 field, this.state.select1 is the text of the selected option. So for example if I select the option with value 3, this.state.select1 is equal to "Whatever".